# lua_Integer and lua_createtable (table size limit)

Tags: c, lua, lua-api, lua-5.3

In Lua 5.3 table related functions in the C API receive and return `lua_Integer`.

```c
void lua_rawgeti (lua_State *L, int idx, lua_Integer n);
void lua_rawseti (lua_State *L, int idx, lua_Integer n);
lua_Integer luaL_len (lua_State *L, int index);
```

But, `lua_createtable` still receives `int`.

```c
void lua_createtable (lua_State *L, int narr, int nrec);
```

In the example function below the length of the source table is used to create a copy which is the same size.

```c
static int copy_sequence(lua_State *L) {
   lua_Integer len, i;
   luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
   len = luaL_len(L, 1);
   lua_createtable(L, (int)len, 0); /* conversion warning */
   for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
      lua_rawgeti(L, 1, i);
      lua_rawseti(L, -2, i);
   }
   return 1;
}
```

But, a cast is required to silence the warning:

> warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘lua_Integer’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Searching on the Lua mailing list I found the following [thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-08/msg00041.html) which is about Lua 5.2 (applies to earlier versions too I'm assuming):

> Quote: Roberto Ierusalimschy (7 Aug 2012)
>
> The size of tables is already limited to 2147483647 elements. Lua
>   internally uses 'int' to index all its arrays (except for strings/byte
>   arrays). It is a pain to work with unsigned values (such as size_t)
>   everywhere; ptrdiff_t has no garanties at all.

Is this still the case for Lua 5.3 which uses `long long` for `lua_Integer`? Is the cast to `int` from `lua_Integer` as used in the example above safe in Lua 5.3?

Comment: This question seems more suitable to the Lua mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of a table (number of elements) is still limited to 'int'. That
does not prevent a table from having arbitrary lua_Integer keys (as long
as the table is not a proper sequence).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I was actually writing up a post to lua-l when I saw your answer.